# Which algorithm is used to implement search for files in Visual Studio Code / Google Chrome Developer / Sublime (Ctrl+p or Cmd+p)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, google-chrome-devtools, sublimetext3

I am very impressed with the powerful search feature of Sublime which we later found in Visual Studio Code and Google Chrome Developer.

A very basic algorithm for searching may use Trie, I guess but this search for files of Sublime etc seems like some sort of a multi-direction Trie (if there is such a thing!) i.e. if you have a file name like:

"I-am-a-very-big-beautifully-created-file-and-something-else.js"

and you search for "created file", "file created", "something-beautifully", "else big", "big else" or any other combination of strings from that file's name, Sublime and Visual Studio code will find it and other files with similar names, in no time. (Google Chrome Developer version isn't very powerful though but that's not the point here).

So, I dug through the source code of Visual Studio for a little bit but still couldn't figure out how the search is implemented and which algorithm is used. I am not looking for its code. Just need to understand a high level theory of how this powerful feature, that saves us developers a lot of time, is implemented.

Comment: I don't know about VS Code or Chrome, and Sublime is closed source and proprietary, but probably [this blog post](https://blog.forrestthewoods.com/reverse-engineering-sublime-text-s-fuzzy-match-4cffeed33fdb) will give you some ideas.

Comment: @OdatNurd very helpful indeed. Thanks. :)

Comment: I wish VSCode would change theirs to be more like Sublime's...

Comment: @ScottStafford How is the sublime one different?

Comment: I don't know exactly, since it's opaque. But it feels like it finds the file I want quicker and higher in it's list.  It also feels like it remembers what you choose with certain search strings and therefore learns you.  Not sure though, I havent studied it methodically.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The VS Code functionality you're looking for can be tracked by looking into what happens when this function is called:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/src/vs/workbench/contrib/search/browser/anythingQuickAccess.ts#L365

an interesting part here (filter on the first term only , then on the whole filter):

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/d1220da07267242e9b58193da0ded43bbe7f2aa5/src/vs/workbench/contrib/search/browser/anythingQuickAccess.ts#L570

If you dig from there you will find that most of the useful stuff is regrouped in this file:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/src/vs/base/common/fuzzyScorer.ts

Some notes:

The fuzzy search is pretty strict, the filter will not match if a single letter is not found or if the letters are not found in the right order. A key advantage is that you can highlight the matching part in the results and it makes pretty clear what's happening to your users.

The fuzzy scorer scores results based on a matching label/description[/path] (for a file, label = filename, description = path without name).

Answer (score 4):

This looks like the code that DevTools uses for its fuzzy search in the [Command Menu](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/ui#command-menu).

https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/devtools/front_end/quick_open/CommandMenu.js?l=174

And the underlying diff algorithm is:

https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/devtools/front_end/diff/Diff.js?q=Diff.Diff&dr=CSs&l=4

Comment: Chromium's DevTools algo is not good enough IMO. For it to work, you have to type the searched word in order. e.g. if your target file name is "chromium-dev-tool-dummy-file.txt" and you search for "tool dev chromium", the file will not appear. In visual studio, you can search for any combination of those words and the search result will work as expected.

Answer (score 3):

I think the name is "fuzzy search" lol.  Here's a nice github repo where some kind person released an open source JS version that is a lot easier to include in your code than the VS Code version because it's on npm and it's just one file:

https://github.com/farzher/fuzzysort