# Highlight partial matches from array of strings - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I'm creating a small project which will go through the contents of a textarea element, find words from the banned words list and highlight them if they are found. I've implemented a solution which works for full words, however in the scenario of edge cases, I've run into quite the pickle. Below is the code from the project:

```
const bannedWords = ['treatment', 'cancer', 'allergens'];
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    let checkButton = document.querySelector('.check__btn');
    let textArea = document.querySelector('textarea');

    checkButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let inputString = textArea.value.split(" ");
        for (let i = 0; i < inputString.length; i++) {

            if (bannedWords.includes(inputString[i])) {
                inputString[i] = `<mark>${inputString[i]}</mark>`;
            }
        }
        let outputText = document.querySelector('.output__text');
        outputText.innerHTML = inputString.join(" ");

        return false;
    });
});
```

So for example, if a user was to input 'treat' or 'cancerous' for example, they won't be highlighted since they technically don't appear in the list.

Any help with this would be appreciated! Cheers.

Comment: In this case, instead of `includes` you have to loop your `bannedWords` array and then check with `equal` condition.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is quite similar to what vscode files search does. When you hit Ctrl+P and enter some file name for eg: "numbrepinut" it would still show you the file named numberInput.js considering it a similar result.
Please check the following links:

1. [Which algorithm is used to implement search for files in Visual Studio Code / Google Chrome Developer / Sublime (Ctrl+p or Cmd+p)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49138685/which-algorithm-is-used-to-implement-search-for-files-in-visual-studio-code-go)
2. https://levelup.gitconnected.com/fuzzy-searches-in-vs-code-tips-to-increase-developer-focus-and-productivity-6809c0f3ce9a

Comment: It's better to avoid answers which rely too heavily on information only provided in links. See [Your answer is in another castle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/671985). Instead, try to provide the relevant details directly in the answer itself (and use links for additional resources, attribution, etc.).